# Clearing crontab changed format of terminal cron messaging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, cron, whenever

I'm using the latest version of the whenever gem with Rails 3.1.1 for cron tasks.  After I used the whenever command on the terminal

```
whenever -c
```

to clear the crontab, whenever I type in

```
crontab -l
```

whereas it used to say something like "there are no cron tasks" (this is not verbatim) now it just displays a blank space about the size of two empty lines.  Also if I have a cron task setup and I type the same command into the terminal again, those two empty lines come up before it shows the cron tasks.  I'm sorry if this is a minor issue.  Everything appears to be working fine but I just want to make sure I didn't screw anything up that'll come back to haunt me somewhere down the line.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the task in the schedule.rb file which is generated by whenever gem.

After changing your cron task in the schedule.rb you have to update your crontab file and you can use this command to do that :-

whenever --update-crontab f(here f is your application name)

crontab -l is used to see your current crontab file.

Hope it helps

Comment: I guess I didnt understand the question in that case :)